# Disable pinch to zoom for external keyboard w/ trackpad mac ventura

Tags: mac, keyboard, bluetooth, touchpad

I have a bluetooth keyboard with a touchpad connected to a macbook running Ventura. I find that the bluetooth keyboard and touchpad, don't respect the mac os system settings I have for my keyboard. In particular, pinch to zoom, despite being disabled in my system preferences is still enabled for the touchpad on the keyboard.

I've done some searching for a solution, but most solutions seem to be outdated. I would settle for something that just disables pinch to zoom in chrome, there seem to be some solutions to that, but they rely on now-removed settings that would disable pinch to zoom in chrome.

Maybe worth noting, but this seems to be generally my keyboard settings don't apply either. For instance, I have caps lock set to be a control key, but on the bluetooth keyboard it's still caps lock.

Answer (score 0):

idk whether the same applies to trackpads [I don't have any to test], so only a partial answer.

Keyboard modifiers can be selected per keyboard. There's a list at the top of the Modifier Keys… dialog.

[image]

<sup>The locations of prefs have all changed in Ventura, but the functionality remains the same.</sup>

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful for the keyboard settings. But there isn't an equivalent for the trackpad settings as far as I can tell.

Comment: Sorry. I knew this was only half an answer, but had no way to test.